# Function Parameter Dynamic Type Based Off First Parameter

Tags: function, typescript, visual-studio-code

Right now I have a very generic function that when my client talks to my server, it hits.  So to keep it very flexible, I am doing this:

```
public call(method: string, ...parameters: any[]) {}
```

On my server though, I keep all the methods together like such:

```
MethodManager.methods({
    findOne: {
        function: function(collection: string, query: Object) {
            return model(collection).findOne(query).exec();
        }
    },
    find: {
        function: function(collection: string, query: Object, sortQuery: Object = {}) {
            return model(collection).find(query).sort(sortQuery).exec();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, each method may have different parameters.  When I write code on the client, I am not able to use the full potential of Typescript because it is 'any' casted.

How can I make this so that visual studio code would recognize that when I write this line of code:

```
this.socketManager.call('findOne',
```

It would pop up with a helper list like so:

```
(method: 'findOne', collection: string, query: Object)
```

But when I type:

```
this.socketManager.call('find',
```

It gives me:

```
(method: 'find', collection: string, query: Object, sortQuery: Object = {})
```

Instead of the unhelpful:

```
(method: string, ...parameters: any[])
```

Is this possible? It would be a drastic help for development.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to achieve this by writing a script that goes through all the method files, parse through them and grab the functions and parameters out.  This script is being run on compilation of the server code (picks up changes), and then re-creates a generated methods.ts file on the client which I load up on startup.

```
export function SERVER_METHODS(socketManager) {
    return {
        findOne: (collection: string, query: Object, cb?: Function)  => {
            socketManager.call('findOne', collection, query, cb);
        },
        find: (collection: string, query: Object, sortQuery: Object = {}, cb?: Function)  => {
            socketManager.call('find', collection, query, sortQuery, cb);
        },
        ...
    };
}
```

Then I am using this like so:

```
public methods = SERVER_METHODS(this);
```

And now instead of doing this:

```
this.socketManager.call('findOne', ...)
```

I am doing this:

```
this.socketManager.methods.findOne(
```

And that gives me the parameters for that function.  Pretty manual solution but it works and is now automated.

Comment: since you are using a script to generate the types, it seems like it would be long off from the best practice

Comment: No refactoring of code, automated within the build scripts, and quick and easy script. Sometimes you have to do things outside the norm to achieve the customization you want. Best practice is not always best

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation. I had to send an event when the user Logs in and Logs out.
I wanted to make a sendEvent function so that the second argument, payload object with userId is mandatory if we pass first argument login type = 'LOG_IN', however, the second argument can be optional if the event type = "LOG_OUT".
This is how I tackled, You can do something similar:

```
export type Event = { type: 'LOG_IN'; payload: { userId: string } } | { type: 'LOG_OUT' };

const sendEvent = <Type extends Event['type']>(
  ...args: Extract<Event, { type: Type }> extends { payload: infer TPayload } ? [type: Type,payload: TPayload] : [Type]
) => {
  // Send event stuff

};

sendEvent('LOG_IN', {userId: 'id1'})
sendEvent('LOG_OUT');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this with function overloads in Typescript: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html

Here is [an example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0Afunction%20call(method%3A%20%22find%22%2C%20collection%3A%20string%2C%20query%3A%20object)%3A%20object%3B%0D%0Afunction%20call(method%3A%20%22findOne%22%2C%20collection%3A%20string%2C%20query%3A%20object%2C%20sortQuery%3A%20object)%3A%20object%5B%5D%3B%0D%0Afunction%20call(method%3A%20%22find%22%20%7C%20%22findOne%22%2C%20...parameters%3A%20any%5B%5D)%3A%20any%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20switch%20(method)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20%22find%22%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20%5Bcollection%2C%20query%5D%20%3D%20parameters%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20%22findOne%22%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20%5Bcollection%2C%20query%2C%20sortQuery%5D%20%3D%20parameters%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%5B%7B%7D%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Acall(%22find%22%2C%20%22collection%22%2C%20%7B%7D)%0D%0Acall(%22findOne%22%2C%20%22collection%22%2C%20%7B%7D%2C%20%7B%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0Acall(%22find%22%2C%20%22collection%22%2C%20%7B%7D%2C%20%7B%7D)%20%2F%2F%20Error%0D%0Acall(%22findOne%22%2C%20%22collection%22%2C%20%7B%7D)%20%2F%2F%20Error%0D%0A):

```
function call(method: "find", collection: string, query: object): object;
function call(method: "findOne", collection: string, query: object, sortQuery: object): object[];
function call(method: "find" | "findOne", ...parameters: any[]): any {
    switch (method) {
        case "find": {
            const [collection, query] = parameters
            return {}
        }
        case "findOne": {
            const [collection, query, sortQuery] = parameters
            return [{}]
        }

    }
}

call("find", "collection", {})
call("findOne", "collection", {}, {})

call("find", "collection", {}, {}) // Error
call("findOne", "collection", {}) // Error
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for.  Two more questions arise.  1. Can this be done dynamically?  For example if my server sends a list of possible method calls on connection start, can the client take that list and create a dynamic version of your answer?  2. Is there a way to take the MethodManager.methods (which is just an array of methods) and pull out the function parameters it needs for each function?

Comment: Sure, I could see generating this dynamically. From that server response, I believe it would just be a matter of iterating over it and emitting a call signature for each one. If it were me, I would probably generate a client with a separate function for each of the methods, rather than a single call function. i.e. you would actually have `client.find`, `client.findOne` defined.